# ssh says: You don't exist, go away!

Tags: ssh

Sometimes when I try to `ssh` to a server, I get the following message:

```
You don't exist, go away!
```

I haven't seen this before using `ssh`. What does this mean? Is there a problem with ssh or something else? 
Additional info:

```
ssh -q -i private_key root@192.168.0.11 "command"
```

The server is a SUSE Linux.
I run the `ssh` command in a loop 10 times, and only 1 or 2 of the tries result in the Go away message.

Comment: Please try searching before asking questions. This is a standard error message and a 5 minute search should tell you what it means. Also, qhen asking Qs, remember to include your OS, the OS of the machine you are connecting to, the output of `ssh -vv` etc etc.

Comment: I did actually, but all the results were related to the /etc/passwd file. So I am not sure if my case is the same!

Comment: OK, in that case mention it, tell us the OSs in question, tell us what you've ruled out, show us the output of `ssh -vv`, explain why you think your problem is not related to `/etc/password` (hint: it probably is, the error is complaining about a user who doesn't exist right?). How are you authenticating to the machine? Is there a centralized authentication server? What options if any are you passing to `ssh`? Give us something to work with!

Comment: I tend to agree with [Joel](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) about simple questions and this question made me feel interested. However, @coffeMug, if you have a problem, please describe it clearly (and document what you have tried in order to solve it).

Comment: @terdon I provided some more info.

Comment: " I run the ssh command in a loop for 10 times and only 1 or 2 of the tries result in the Go away message." That's _exactly_ the kind of thing you need to mention, it kinda changes everything :).

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889557/you-dont-exist-go-away-what-does-this-heroku-error-mean help? The error usually means that `ssh` on your client system (not the server) can't determine your username. Several programs emit this error message. You could encounter it when running `ssh` from a `su` or `sudo` session. I think I encountered it after I ran 'login' in a terminal window to change my userid; this screws up the `utmp` file.

Comment: @coffeMug Is this the exact error message?  It's more likely to be `You don't exist, go away!` (note the punctuation).

Comment: @Mikel Right! Fixed.

Comment: Two more pieces of info we could use: the OS and distribution name of the _client_ system (not the server), and a statement of whether, in a terminal window that gets the `You don't exist` error, running the command `who am i` returns either an error or an incorrect username.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `who am i` is OK returning my user id. And OS is a specialized version of SUSE.

Comment: OK. See Mikel's answer for guidance. It sounds like you're having intermittent problems contacting the `passwd` name service. Maybe whatever server you're using for that name service is rate-limited, or is running out of sockets. We ran into problems occasionally on a MacOSX server with a "10 user" license.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Unfortunately yes!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error message is probably coming from `ssh` on your own machine.  [Source](http://repo.or.cz/w/openssh-git.git/blob/HEAD:/ssh.c#l273)

This happens if `ssh` can't find your username in the `passwd` database.

You can try running `getent passwd $USERNAME` multiple times and seeing if that fails.

Depending on how `passwd` lookup is configured, try one of these:

- Ensure your username appears in `/etc/passwd`
- Ensure that `sssd` or `nscd` is running properly, if appropriate
- Ensure that your connection to the account server, e.g. NIS, LDAP, etc. is working
- Check the system log files on your computer (`/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`, etc.)

If you post the output of `grep '^passwd' /etc/nsswitch.conf`, along with any interesting parts of `ssh -vv` output and system logs, people can probably help more.

Comment: This seems to be the correct explanation of the problem. :-)

Comment: This can commonly happen if you are authenticating via an LDAP server and the Polkit policies (or similar) don't correctly add you into any local groups. SSH and other core system tools only look at /etc/passwd and don't understand PAM/etc without help, or sometimes at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you change an account's UID, any existing shell will have this sort of identity crisis. Check by comparing UID from output of "id" and do a `grep $(whoami) /etc/passwd`. if changing UID, be sure to check for any crontab entries for the user!