# Cannot reverse port forwarding with SSH as temporary user

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, socks

I own linux machine A and have a limited access to linux machine B. Both machine have Internet access.

Internet access on machine A is partially censored so I want to make a SOCKS proxy tunnel through machine B.

Since I cannot forward ports opened on machine B (which is behind a router) so I decided to make a reverse SSH connection from B to A as described [here](https://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/).

However it seems I cannot use SSH on machine B as normally:

```
$ ssh #on machine B
No user exists for uid 57521
$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 57521
```

My situation is like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113863/ssh-says-you-dont-exist-go-away).

Each time I log into machine B, my UID will change. After some research, it seems I probably logged in machine B as LDAP user or something alike.

I don't have write access to `/etc` on machine B. **How do I setup SSH in this case? Or is there any alternative method setup a reverse SOCKS proxy, preferably encrypted?**

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to setup SSH at the end, however I found the tool `ssocks` suitable for my need, although lacking a bit encryption.

1. Download `ssocks` from the Sourceforge [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ssocks/files/latest/download). Then execute:

   ```
   tar -zxvf ssocks*.tar.gz
   cd ssocks-*; ./configure
   make -j4
   ```
2. Now, in `ssocks-*/src/` directory, there should be a client `rcsocks` and a server `rsscoks`. Copy `rssocks` to machine B
3. Execute the following:

   on machine A:

   `./rcsocks -p <relay_port> -l 1080`

   on machine B:

   `./rssocks --socks <ip_of_machine_a>:<relay_port>`

   Fill in `<ip_of_machine_a>` and `<relay_port>` as per need.
4. The socks proxy is now available at `127.0.0.1:1080` on machine A.